# Errors while integrating Funambol SDK into my iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, compiler-errors, build-error

I have an application in which i am integrating funambol sdk. When i build the code, there is an error **No such file or directory**. I had add these files to xcode, but still it shows as file missing i.e., in red color. See attached screenshot:

[image]
Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you delete the files of the sdk from the project file? I mean not from the xcode, from the project file?

Comment: No, i delete files from xcode and then i add from project folder.

Comment: Can you please provide the link from where you got the SDK and their project code for iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the files from your project folder and delete the references from Xcode. Now add them again. Make sure that you've enabled the checkbox to "Copy items into destination group's folder" if you want to have them stored with your project.

[image: Xcode copy files when adding to project]

### Edit

Your problem has nothing to do with Xcode or any "file not found" problems. The Funambol SDK looks like a big mess. The most recent version for iOS seems to be at:

> svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/funambol/code/apple-clients/branches/iphone/v12.1

There's a (obviously outdated) `how_to_build.txt` file, which isn't any help.

You may use the Xcode project at `funambol-sdk/build/mac/libfunambol.xcodeproj` instead to build `libfunambol.a`.

If you're looking for an example how to integrate the lib in your app, `iPhoneMediaHub.xcodeproj` may be a good starting point. However, integrating complex projects/libraries like this one require a fair bit of knowledge and the Funambol developers could have done a much better job by providing an easy-to-integrate framework.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. But now i get an error of **No such file for `libfunambol.a`**

Answer (score 0):

no need to write the path of the file u can directly write

```
#import constant.h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the 'missing files' and then manually select the folder where they are located by clicking this button:

[image]

You should see this dialog appear:

[image]

You can then select the folder that contains all the 'broken' files.

NOTE: If this does not fix all of the missing files, make sure you have the 'Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)' checkbox **checked** when adding files to the project:
[image]

Hope this helps.